# Is there simple usort in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

In PHP, [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function takes two arguments: array to sort and a callback. The callback takes two arguments as well: $a and $b. Then, we compare those two in any way we want. It always surprises me, because this use case for [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is not too common. We usually sort values by the same property or using the same logics for both $a and $b. For example, if we want to sort by the length:

```
$animals = ['dog', 'tiger', 'giraffe', 'bear'];

usort($animals, function ($a, $b) {
    return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
});
```

That will work, but we need to say `strlen` twice. It would be nicer to say it that way:

```
usort($animals, function ($element) {
    return strlen($element);
});
```

Or even like this:

```
usort($animals, 'strlen');
```

I have written this kind of function myself (using PHP 7 goodies, but it can be easily changed to PHP 5):

```
function simple_usort(array &$array, callable $callback): bool
{
    return usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($callback) {
        return $callback($a) <=> $callback($b);
    });
}
```

It works perfectly, but isn't it built in PHP already in some other function? If not, why PHP doesn't support this very popular and convenient way of sorting?

Comment: for the last part, you might want to ask the php group instead of us...lol

Comment: I've never used usort before, and looking at this, I'm kinda confused by the callback function. The strlen of $a is 3, and the strlen of $b is 5. So 3-5 is -2? How does it use the number -2 to sort $a and $b? Sorry, I know you're the one asking the questions here, but I'm just very curious.

Comment: @Andrew You are right, but it's when I'm sure I'm not missing something. The "why" here means "Am I missing something?".

Comment: @frosty usort works this way, where negative callback results are kept in $a, $b order, positive are kept in $b, $a order and 0 doesn't change the order between two elements. This minus technique is like a shortcut, people usually return -1, 0 or 1 in usort callbacks. I could have said `strlen($a) > strlen($b) ? 1 : (strlen($a) < strlen($b) ? -1 : 0)`.

Comment: It might seem nicer to you to use `function ($element) {
    return strlen($element);
}` but wouldn't be very practical..... the callback for usort is ___comparing___ __two__ elements ($a and $b), not simply returning a piece of information about one ($element)

Comment: However, you could write your "special" generic callback without needing PHP7 for the spaceship operator using `function simple_usort(array &$array, callable $callback)
{
    return usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($callback) {
        return $callback($a) - $callback($b);
    });
}`

Comment: `why PHP doesn't support this very popular and convenient way of sorting?` It does with PHP7, as you yourself have demonstrated :)

Comment: Because it's neither popular nor convenient. What *is* popular *and* convenient is the existing `usort()` functionality which you can use to implement your own sorting functions, no matter how inadvisable or esoteric, as you've already done here.

Comment: @MarkBaker My function is doing the same thing as usort, not just returning piece of information.

Comment: @Sammitch Neither popular nor convenient? Can you explain? I wonder how many times you have used usort to do something else than simply sort array by some property of $a and $b, and then used cmp functions or this trick of `$a - $b`. This is duplication of simple logics and I wouldn't call this -1/0/1 approach readable at all.

Comment: Your simple_usort() is doing the same thing, because it's executing a comparison; but `usort($animals, function ($element) {
    return strlen($element);
});` is simply returning a simple piece of information about one record, that's what I meant

Comment: @MarkBaker I still don't get your point. It's returning the piece of information that will be used for sorting and compared to. What is wrong with it? In my opinion it makes much more sense in most cases than comparing $a to $b explicitly in your function.

Comment: @RoboRobok if it were "popular" I would expect to have seen it at least once before during my career, and it's not exactly "convenient" to boil your sort keys down to simple numerical values. As well, your entire argument is based on "I have to type `strlen()` twice" rather than any *real* concern like `strlen()` needing to be *run* many times on any given key.

Answer (score 2):

> It works perfectly, but isn't it built in PHP already in some other function?

No.

> If not, why PHP doesn't support this very popular and convenient way of sorting?

A language should be designed to provide *generic* tools to get things done without supplying a multitude of functions to cater for certain use cases that may or may not be popular, granted that performance isn't negatively impacted by such a decision.

Comment: Well, PHP provides much more exotic functions than the one I mentioned. Arrays alone have tons of built in functions in PHP, some of which are not generic at all.

Comment: @RoboRobok Yeah, I was careful to omit the part where php violates some of those language design best practices ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Since nobody requested it and nobody implemented it.

PHP is driven by people having a patch or people motivating others to write a patch. If a feature is hardly interesting for anybody it isn't requested and isn't implemented.

I believe the feature you want is too specific and the gain is too small.

But if you want it: Add a feature request via bugs.php.net or propose a patch via github.